# How to use JSON to create output

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a json file structured like this :

```
[
    {
    "style":"h1",
    "content":"this is h1"
    },
    {
      "style":"p",
      "content":"this is a long paragraphe "
    },
    {
      "style":"img",
      "content":"image1.jpg"
    },
    {
    "style":"h2",
    "content":"this is h2"
    },
    {
    "style":"h3",
    "content":"this is h3"
    },
    {
    "style":"h1",
    "content":"this is h1 number 2"
    },
    {
      "style":"p",
      "content":"this is a long paragraphe 2 "
    },
    {
      "style":"img",
      "content":"image2.jpg"
    },
    {
    "style":"h2",
    "content":"this is h2 number 2"
    },
    {
    "style":"h3",
    "content":"this is h3 number 2"
    }  
]
```

And I need it to have the output in JavaScript like this:

```
this is h1
this is h2
this is h3
this is a long paragraphe
image1.jpg 
this is h1 number 2
this is h2 number 2
this is h3 number 2
this is a long paragraphe 2
image2.jpg
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: (I've fixed it for you.)

Comment: Man, @T.J.Crowder you're seriously fast

Comment: @Luca: If you mean typing the comments, I didn't. I have bookmarklets for that. :-D

Comment: I meant the editing, I have a GitHub Gist for my comments as well ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please share them bookmarklets! :D

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.forEach() does the job. Iterating through the list too.

```js
var data=[
  {"style":"h1","content":"this is h1"},
  {"style":"p","content":"this is a long paragraphe "}
];
data.forEach(function(elt){
  console.log(elt.content);
});
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  console.log(data[i].content);
}
```

If your json file has not been fetched yet, fetch it using an ajax request and proceed as above. (introduction to ajax requests: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

```js
// creates an Ajax object to fetch the content of a file
var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET","data.json",false);
ajax.send();

// dataString contains the .json file as a string
var dataString=ajax.response;

// we parse it (ie convert it into a javascript object)
var dataObject=JSON.parse(dataString);

// and we iterate through it
for (var i=0; i<dataObject.length; i++){
  console.log(dataObject[i].content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using jQuery and you're trying to get the file and just print the "content" without the html tags.

```
<div id="output">
    <!-- here we'll write the output-->
</div>
<script>
    $.get('your_json_file.json',function(data){
        var data = JSON.parse(data); //may not be neccesary, it depends on how you output your json
        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            //here you get each object of the array. You only want the content
            $('#output').append('<p>' + value.content + '</p>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes ,i want only the content ,but i want it depending on the value of "style" in json,i want 'h1' and 'h2' and 'h3' to appear first what ever their placement is ,then the 'p' and 'img'...

Comment: But do you really want to loose the tag info (whether it's p, h1, h2...)?

Comment: And question nº2: You can't order those tags correctly. How the code is going to know that "this is h2 number 2" comes after the first `<p>`? Maybe you need to add some "block" variable:

`    {
      "block": 1,
      "style":"h1",
      "content":"this is h1"
    },
    {
      "block": 2,
      "style":"p",
      "content":"this is a long paragraphe "
    },`

so you can order them by 1) block 2) style

Comment: i want to keep the same structure of json and i want to display them on order h1, h2, h3 then p, img

Comment: Yes, but that's not the order you are showing us in your original question. There you have an `h3` after an `h1`, for example. And according to the order you're proposing here, it would be all `h1`'s first, all `h2`'s after, etc

Comment: i want to order when displaying whatever json starts with h2 or h3 ... in the display i want to display first h1 then h2 .. etc